# Как на OpenGL создать движущуюся линию сверху вниз

Tags: opengl

Нашел на https://www.shadertoy.com/ похожий шейдер, но не могу понять механизм, чтобы сделать просто линию, движущуюся вниз один раз. Кому не сложно, прошу помочь.
Ссылка на шейдер https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MllBzs
Код на GLSL

```
float rand(vec2 co){
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;//Condensing this into one line
    vec4 texColor = texture(iChannel0, uv);//Get the pixel at xy from iChannel0
    
    float gt = 30.0;// + rand(vec2(iTime, iTime)) * 3.0;
    float m = mod(iTime, 1.0);
    bool glitch = m < 0.5;
    float t = floor(iTime * gt) / gt;
    float r = rand(vec2(t, t));
    
    if(glitch) {
        
        vec2 uvGlitch = uv;
        uvGlitch.x -= r / 5.0;
        if(uv.y > r && uv.y < r + 0.01) {
            texColor = texture(iChannel0, uvGlitch);
        }
    }
    
    fragColor = texColor;
    //fragColor = vec4(uv,0.5+0.5*sin(iTime),1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

За повтор отвечает вот эта строчка:

```
float m = mod(iTime, 1.0); // Остаток от деления
```

Если повтор не нужен, то можно сильно сократить код:

```
float r = 1.0 - iTime; // Инвертируем, чтобы линия шла сверху-вниз

vec2 uvGlitch = uv;
uvGlitch.x -= r / 5.0;
if(uv.y > r && uv.y < r + 0.01) {
    texColor = texture(iChannel0, uvGlitch);
}
```

Но вам придется правильно выбирать `iTime` чтобы увидеть линию.